# Cancelling async uploading task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've got an `Uploader`class with one method -`Upload`

```
public static int Upload(string endpoint,object objectToBeUploaded)
    {
        Source.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        var repos = new UploadRepository(endpoint);
        return repos.Upload(objectToBeUploaded);
    }
```

The `Source` is a static `CancellationTokenSource` available in the project.

I also have a list of endpoints I need to upload a certain `object` for.

The code in the `Form` (it's a very small project using `WinForms`) looks like this:

```
private async Task UploadObjectAsync(
            string endpoint,
            object objectToBeUploaded)
     {
        try
        {
            int elementId  = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () => Uploader.Upload(endpoint,objectToBeUploaded));
           //do something with the returned value..
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledEception ex)
        {
          //handle the exception..
        }
     }
```

And then I set the `btnUpload.Click` handler like this so I can later use it:

```
this.btnUpload.Click += async (s, e) =>
{
   foreach(var endpoint in endpoints)
   {
       await UploadObjectASsync(endpoint,someObject);
   }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I start uploading to all the endpoints(how they are obtained is irrelevant) and I decide to cancel the uploading process using `Source.Cancel();` the first `UploadObjectAsync`will always go through since
the `Source.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` check in the `Upload` method has already been passed. The rest of tasks will be cancelled normally and handled gracefully.

How am I to restructure this code in order to make sure that the first `UploadObjectAsync` `Task` will also be cancelled?

It is worth mentioning that I also don't have access to the source code of the uploading process itself (service reference) -  the `repos.Upload(objectToBeUploaded)` in my `Upload` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your UploadRepository.Upload take a CancellationToken. 
Specially when that's the one doing the I/O operation.. That's when the `async/await` really pays-off.

That will also help you get rid of that: `Task.Factory.StartNew` since the `Upload` method will return Task already. There will be no need to spin off a task.

In your current setup, given enough time for the tasks to start (and go through your `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`) you won't be able to cancel any upload. Even if it takes 30 seconds.

Also, you might be interested in: [Task.Run](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything practical you can do. The Upload method doesn't take a token. The first task has already passed the cancelation check by the time you hit the cancel button. You can prove to yourself the cancel is a timing issue by adding a 10 second sleep ahead of throw if cancelled call. All tasks would then cancel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't stop the process that happens inside the `Upload` function unless it checks for the state of the `CancellationToken` any terminates itself.

So what you could do is to abort the thread that is executing by doing something like this:

```
int elementId  = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
  try
  {
    using (Source.Token.Register(Thread.CurrentThread.Interrupt))
    {
      return Uploader.Upload(endpoint, objectToBeUploaded));
    }
  }
  catch (ThreadInterruptedException ex)
  {
     throw new OperationCanceledEception(ex)
  }
}, Source.Token);
```

Using the [`Source.Token.Register(delegate)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd321635.aspx) function you cause the token to call that function in case the token is cancelled. This way the thread that is currently executing the the uploaded and should throw a exception right away.

This method only works in case the thread enters the **WaitSleepJoin**-State from time to time, because the exception is only raised in case the thread is in that state. Have a look at the documentation of the [`Thread.Interrupt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) function.

The alternative is to use [`Thread.Abort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx) and the `ThreadAbortedException`. This will kill your thread in any case, but it may corrupt the internal state of your service, because locks the thread holds won't be released properly. So be very careful using this method.

Comment: Worth mentioning that's really not advised.

Comment: Yeah... but interrupting the thread should be relatively safe.

Comment: Yeah. The Upload code should still be changed. Though if that's out of his control, then this would be the way to go.